# Input Validation in Python with low and high boundary

Tags: python, validation, input

I need help creating a function to make sure the user's input is valid for use. If it is not valid, then we need to ask them to re-enter a different information.

The first function needs would have the parameter, prompt, low, high, where prompt ask the user for input, the low is the lower boundary and high is the upper boundary.

Here is what I have so far:

```
def get_int(prompt,low,high):
 inputs= int(input(prompt))
while inputs<= low and inputs >=high:
   inputs= int(input(prompt))
return inputs
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your conditions in a weird order.

This will make sure that the input is between the low and high boundaries. If it is, the input is returned, otherwise it's asked again. I added a little optional message to inform the user of the expected range.

```
def get_int(prompt, low, high):
    while True:
       inputs = int(input(prompt))
       if low <= inputs <= high:
           return inputs
#      else:
#          print(f"Please provide a number between {low} and {high}.")
```

Answer (score 0):

If `inputs <= low` is true, then `inputs >= high` can't be true at the same time. So checking if both are true at once via `inputs <= low and inputs >= high` doesn't make sense and will always be false. Your code would work fine if you used an `or` instead of an `and`:

```
def get_int(prompt,low,high):
    inputs = int(input(prompt))
    while inputs <= low or inputs >= high:
        inputs = int(input(prompt))
    return inputs
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use recursion? Like this:

```
def user_input():
    value = input("Please enter input: ")
    if not low <= value <= high:
        user_input()
    return value
```

Recusion works only until a certain depth, but this may be thousands of inputs.